# Javascript alert header

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I write 2 php pages, index.php & form.php, when user submit form in index.php, then form.php process and check whether email is duplicate, so I write in form.php like this

```
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=big5');
header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
echo "<Script language=JavaScript>alert('email exist！');</Script>";
```

if the email exist, page will return to index.php, I hope the input text box still keep what the user enter, and have a alert box in index.php to remind them the email exist,

But I try different way, but the alert box cannot be shown in index.php, I know nothing will output before header, I also try `ob_start()`,

Can anyone teach me how can I check email duplication in form.php, and then just go back to index.php without refresh, also the user input still appear, also index.php can display an alert box to remind user, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

it should be `script` NOT `Script`

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('email exist！');</script>";
```

**EDIT :** if you are redirecting back to `index.php` and the alert is in `form.php` so it will never fire you have to be on the same page!

Comment: echo "<script language=Javascript>alert('email exist！');</script>";
sorry, It doesn't work

Comment: try `type='text/javascript'` instead of `language=Javascript`

Comment: but, if i try this way, the alert box shown in index.php, then I press ok, it refresh page, my problem is that what the user input will disappear

Comment: header('Content-type:text/html; charset=big5');
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('email exist！');</script>";
header("Refresh:0.0;URL=\"http://XXX");

Answer (score 0):

```
        if(isset($_POST['create'])) //here your submit button

        {
                if(isset($_REQUEST['email']))  
                {   
                    $username = $_POST['email'];       //// textbox value you written email
                    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select email from tablename where email='$username'");
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0)
                    {
                        echo "<script>
                            alert('email already')
                            </script>";
                    }
                 else
                  {
                                //registration code
                   }
}
```

PHP is serverside scripting language and javascript is clicent side scripting language. PHP `header()` function is faster than script that's why 
header() execution fast and it not display.

Comment: Yes, i understand serverside or clientside, so can I also use header() to show warning like javascript alert?

Comment: but, if i try this way, the alert box shown in index.php, then I press ok, it refresh page, my problem is that what the user input will disappear – Wedding Budget 4 mins ago   edit   
     
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=big5'); echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('email exist！');</script>"; header("Refresh:0.0;URL=\"XXX"); – Wedding Budget 4 mins ago   edit

Comment: it is disappear because of refreshing the page. if you don't want to refresh the page used AJAX or html attribute autocomplete=off of textbox.

Comment: it's worth trying, can you give me some real examples of using AJAX or html for my case? thanks!